# How to solve $\int\int_{D} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ over triangular region

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve this integral $$\int\int_{D} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ over triangular region $$ ((x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}  : x ∈ [0,π], 0 ≤ y ≤ x)$$

I've started as $$\int^{\pi}_0\int^{\pi}_x \frac{\sin(y)} {y} dy dx$$ and I got 2 as the result but I'm not sure whether I'm allowed to change the variables and have I determined the range of x and y correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the value of the integral as $2$ easily by integrating w.r.t. $y$ first and then w.r.t. $x$. The integral you have written is more complicated. The given integral is $\int_0^{\pi} \int _0^{x}\frac {\sin x} x dydx=\int_0^{\pi} \sin x dx=2$.

Comment: So the range of y is actually 0 to x and not from x to pi, as I have written it?

Comment: Yes, the range for $y$ is $0$ to $x$.